# Writing a .pdf to sd card in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, encoding

When I have a PDF formatted like so (abbreviated)

```
"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
```

I am able to write it to the sd card with this code, and then open it.

```
            File file = new File(eqnxPath.getAbsolutePath(), FileId + FileName);
            Log.d(TAG, "looking for file...");
            if (file.exists())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "fiel exists, returning file");
                return file;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "file does not exist, making file");
                byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(this.FileContent, Base64.DEFAULT);
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    try
                    {
                        os.write(pdfAsBytes);
                        os.flush();
                        os.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "returning file");
                        return file;
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "IOException...");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FileNotFoundException...");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

However when I get a pdf that looks like this (again abbreviated)

```
%PDF-1.3
%����
1 0 obj
<undefined</Metadata 35 0 R/Pages 2 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</MediaBox[0.0 0.0 609.12 788.88]/Count 1/Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<undefined</Parent 2 0 R/Contents 29 0 R/PieceInfo<undefined</MRC<undefined</Private<undefined</B[1 1 3 1]/I[3 8 300 300]/P[2 0.45]/Q 0.1/S[2 0]/U 0/Y 15/b 20/v 2.31>>/LastModified(D:20121102151622-06'00')>>/PSL<undefined</Private<undefined</V(3.1.902)>>/LastModified(D:20121102211626-00'00')>>>>/MediaBox[0 0.0 609.12 788.88]/Resources<undefined</XObject<</4 28 0 R/5 27 0 R/6 26 0 R/7 23 0 R/8 22 0 R/9 21 0 R/A 20 0 R/B 19 0 R/C 18 0 R/D 17 0 R/E 16 0 R/F 15 0 R/G 14 0 R/H 13 0 R/I 12 0 R/J 11 0 R/K 10 0 R/L 9 0 R/M 8 0 R/N 7 0 R/O 6 0 R/P 5 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/ImageC/ImageI/ImageB]>>/Type/Page/LastModified(D:20121102151622-06'00')>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<undefined</Subtype/Image/Length 20602/Filter/CCITTFaxDecode/ImageMask true/BitsPerComponent 1/Width 2320/DecodeParms<undefined</K -1/Columns 2320>>/Height 2960/Type/XObject>>stream
����KH�r�f(A�:FD���;!�(CǕ��:!������v�p���������������?w�A�?I<��
@� b��r�P�����������O��̓�Gcb��ɘ�("El%A�@���r��S����3����h� �� �Ȑc"@�.�0DE��2PA�.(A�a�8k�)%���L��#A�c'd�Ȑh*f� `�M �(�f�C6���� ��xN��� �0 xA��� `�A�h�2�&�y�TA�x'A��zp����4L a��� 駬?OO�S�������xA���~��N,'��AƐN-;���i����[�[OD~�Zo��q�"2-��*v��[���m�q�!֓rM�'��g8rC�1�`�����%�G�  :!r��"�4fB� G��h�)2c&�tpO��O    ��W��GSAA���:�O!�ɧ�`��5��n@�'���zM�ap���_�&�I�J �n��L8OA�����&�=W   ��xN���H=7  �=7
�!xV��n����n�]7���I�n��.�����&�[���O[���z�Kn~���_�������I�����V��������Z�������������������������"A����������
���ܫ��������������e��� a������/����H3?���������_�ߐq������������ �7�������O�����/��/�!�E���������"�u���������� D���� ���肋��������� ������� ������U����D����Ai��������������_�����\6i������ݿ�K����V�/� c������_���m���0K���"�zo��������c���������������_�������������_���]��������k����_�~�����������������������D������������w��k�������]���������o�J������E����/ۯ����
�_�Z�BA/��^�Jյ���KJ��/���k��[�յm+Xui��������i{a[K�:lڤ�IZ���Z�����k%
v�
��^�0}���$}��cRCRCH�4�l+iCY
m/�a~
)6� L�� ޖ%�lW��3��ȑ�+ �m)�Hb�a/�?��b�67د
5�?�*����**(1_��5��^�[�2
/����5U_쁈�S[�
.�^ �����P��/��A���
B
n������/�va�Bk
���/�
E�����a4"9���"+�
0�  �"�&���Xk�aa��`�!�  ���2�=��j�  ��A��� ����l��e�A������SǨ�����/�_�������:���������
���a!VSZ��������!*�H7龓��W��̓�
��"Ő1��)%
@�;D��)9!� @AAld �`�>�P�u�"D�
9|�rundefined<azv�z�0����zi����za;���L'�קj�A��OT�7^-�'���4�M��\��   G���v�c�<�P��O �o���I�t��M� ������ �zN�y�0�>�:]=����2�5�:O�Ӿ��ivAA?[�ut���S��7a�^��׽�^���P�N����n��Upa�_X�����
���_ޗ�<����Zo��o�[��U�e�X�����_��7��D�]m������@ٷ��_\��������������/u����������������SP+��������#ڧ���������������{��_����^��]�;���^����h�������W����������������د�n����������i[_��]�ڵ�[]�
����K��J�J����m-���յ��]�xk��J�X/�����1V����0�����V!�����_�h5
o�����P�/��O����P����_R�13��RBL���G"Cn�l���K���d���}kV������eP�����Z��� _�e�*Bl�    0ed�3;Z`��9i*��5%����d�iw�z���u����$�~4�߅��o�Q���������ܧ2H.x�X�џ)��Ρ�p�8S�4g'� 0hGS'�<� �=B`�;��u=< �4�?M4� �S��^�ń���M>/�N���ӽPh�v���  ��#�t�܉�Dt!9���O��"��@�����=$��龃A�n�@�7M�o����I=>��t��U:N����T���}7��[WT�+������    .�_�C�=>��=p����������6c6zVf�ޥ�mB� ��?����D^�j��G������������?������-�_������W������$�$c��L� �ד�����FGJFG���鷷��o���u���u��u_^�/����_��}-���ki}�w�u.���Z�v�����Z�]�~��mv�V��Nڶ��k�Z���I��&����L5`�]�}�`˃�lSTW��LS�HM�����
��ڦ�� �i����a���
a��k�����4���+a�A�^��ӴװX0D�&A�M!iq��D�"#������Sz�~�_j�#���������������s\�
٪3��B��)_Q���-Of��^��������?���������_�������_�%����̔����}��EW���TY�~.�5�q�������������������l����:���@��ddj��\φ%�(RFvjɺ� �Oe;j��Yrundefined<W4���j�ddP3S7�`�DNN!K�����0��H!���j�i����!�:3XR��Ä �0���Au�M���M=>&��MQ>!H�\�At�O��8w
{��Z�
$�%N����7�����6r�7�����u��ץ�5�o@��y tO�6    M6��s1�� ���D��v�".9�k&�O*'�d�e�_�0��t�J��U����Fe'ۗ6�ӧk߄����q�+��i����.�w��_�xA��:�}��&��q��oҽ/�Y��!�ҿ_�?�_��1�����M�?�/�ӏ}�_~�_���T����==iid�������W�׭��7�WO�������������_�o����:�����R�_���!����Azվ���z�ȉ�W���Z�]b����W����o���-k�d?�_������~���M����p�_�$��uMR�&-��)����.��o�.�Ip��������$�����������k_��/y/�W���@�~��M�+�,�7��^��5��    �"_ҧ�����qqZ�ﭨ5#��g�{��|A�Σ���J�/�I/��zm'�un�}��������II�)�����_�t�Hw��}���%_�W���K�'�������
�u|^���'�+��/�v�ߧ聟���9�~�Z���w��Z�/�K�\?��^����}-t����ץ��u���v6֟��������]h/^�ƕ{���]��^�R��mwUV�R�Y�%�yѯ�����ۮ�Z���N����}p�5�]+K����U�����y�vҤ
*�����&��I1\���:!���f�0�|V�/��I5���[ˋ�`��SH��a%�b!�
�Ay����aWZU�`�rG�����A��+��E!q��
/����-��X`�0��\�V��E'���[�_��I?���-yᅿ�_�0[�L,4�Imt��zB"8��������0�
;P���)�,��lE�f4�qZ��^��MUZhDb?����j|��"�\���TY*jFǟ�"!D�b���!.�Fdv��*�NdX!6(�����
0����Y�A���gSDԇ��Û�V�A�x �ja��=5��T���C�����ih4�a=4Ӫ����D��|��[�Ӈpk�޿wڧ��:Dp��O(��¥c׾�?֗OY(|�Q�r;�` �������t6��M���K0�����'ϒƲ��'��"%ԏ��(+��n�+������u���
��A�e֛�oKH_��۽������OW��������[_���RYC��޵kh����I�o&�G�ѪZ����w~�-��?���U/���������i/��W߮��[_�����������|$��.��խ������JA6������^D �ҥ����A��J��*���O���5���~�������o�[�T����m/��_����]r �����R���I%����/��lz/M�����0�����W���\��Pa���O��^G��6��%�����z��a�u���U�D0�9��
���Ҧ�K�p�έ����[����Z��?�3������߂��<��XJ�����Km/�����:�#��I~�R�I�]���^���@������ץ���/����ޕ����A'^�.�/�k~��Z   �k��դ��-źJ���~�v����k��AWK�������֯�_��^��U�0�Natˉ��%�ܘ�3�V��0_����y��xk��!���d��)#�undefined<BJ-��1QE��(����A��`�QR�H���jCG
4E�i�װ�
}K1(>�1\;�*��������8[�׿k
��n�[   }�%�
�h��7]���Xk�i�ͅ�+�DG�CB
�pf�����E��d*c��4z�I*���J��P�!��
```

My method does not work. How would I write this type of .pdf to the sd card? I dont even know what type of data I am looking at...

Comment: It looks like a binary which has been viewed (then saved) with some sort of advanced editor and when it was saved, it was basically done using some sort of text representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PDF "formatted" like in your first example is base64 encoded (an encoding used to transport binary data via a channel that can only handle text properly).

Before writing to card, therefore, it has to be decoded which your method does by means of a ' Base64.decode' call.

A PDF "formatted" like in your second example is already in its unencoded state. Thus, no further decoding is necessary and the data has to be written to card as is.

I hope your member variable ' this.FileContent' is not a string but a byte array, or that its byte array representation is present in yet another member. Otherwise the second, unencoded form surely already is broken.

For this kind of data your method shall not call the base64 decode method before saving but instead save the data as is.

Comment: Btw, in your second form i often see "<undefined<" where there should be a simple "<<". This might indicate the data you have is already corrupt.

Comment: Thankyou, I had tried writing it straight to the SD card, and though I was doing something wrong. Now I think it might be the file is just corrupt. I will have to tell the web engineer making the API to just send it always like he did in the first example. Thanks!

Comment: You mention an API and a web engineer. Depending on the communication protocol of the API, it may deliver its data using different transfer encodings as long as the encoding is properly communicated. In case of an API using SOAP with MTOM, different part headers would allow both for base64 encoded and binary, unencoded transfer.